# pure Knuth/Fisher-Yates shuffle in haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming, shuffle, purely-functional

In go I could write a function like this:

```
func pureFisherYates(s []int, swaps []int) []int {
    newS := copy(s)
    for i, _ := range newS {
            for _, j := range swaps {
                    newS[i], newS[j] = newS[j], newS[i]
            }
    }
}
```

To me this seems like a pure function. It always returns the same output given the same input, and it doesn't mutate the state of the world (except in some strict sense the same way that any other function does, taking up cpu resources, creating heat energy, etc). Yet whenever I look for how to do pure shuffling I find stuff like [this](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/perfect-shuffle.txt), and whenever I look for specifically Haskell implementation Fisher-Yates I either get an `0^2` Fisher-Yates implemented with a list or a `[a] -> IO [a]` implementation. Does there exist a `[a] -> [a]` `O(n)` shuffle and if not why is my above go implementation impure.

Comment: That's an interesting collection of facts. What's your question?

Comment: @DanielWagner hopefully I fixed it to make the question more clear

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ST` monad allows exactly such encapsulated mutability, and [`Data.Array.ST`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.3.0/docs/Data-Array-ST.html) contains arrays which can be mutated in `ST` and then an immutable version returned outside.

https://wiki.haskell.org/Random_shuffle gives two implementations of Fisher-Yates shuffle using `ST`. They aren't literally `[a] -> [a]`, but that's because random number generation needs to be handled as well:

```
import System.Random
import Data.Array.ST
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.STRef

-- | Randomly shuffle a list without the IO Monad
--   /O(N)/
shuffle' :: [a] -> StdGen -> ([a],StdGen)
shuffle' xs gen = runST (do
        g <- newSTRef gen
        let randomRST lohi = do
              (a,s') <- liftM (randomR lohi) (readSTRef g)
              writeSTRef g s'
              return a
        ar <- newArray n xs
        xs' <- forM [1..n] $ \i -> do
                j <- randomRST (i,n)
                vi <- readArray ar i
                vj <- readArray ar j
                writeArray ar j vi
                return vj
        gen' <- readSTRef g
        return (xs',gen'))
  where
    n = length xs
    newArray :: Int -> [a] -> ST s (STArray s Int a)
    newArray n xs =  newListArray (1,n) xs
```

and

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Monad.Random
import System.Random
import Data.Array.ST
import GHC.Arr

shuffle :: RandomGen g => [a] -> Rand g [a]
shuffle xs = do
    let l = length xs
    rands <- forM [0..(l-2)] $ \i -> getRandomR (i, l-1)
    let ar = runSTArray $ do
        ar <- thawSTArray $ listArray (0, l-1) xs
        forM_ (zip [0..] rands) $ \(i, j) -> do
            vi <- readSTArray ar i
            vj <- readSTArray ar j
            writeSTArray ar j vi
            writeSTArray ar i vj
        return ar
    return (elems ar)

*Main> evalRandIO (shuffle [1..10])
[6,5,1,7,10,4,9,2,8,3]
```

EDIT: with a fixed `swaps` argument as in your Go code, the code is quite simple

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Foldable
import Control.Monad.ST

shuffle :: forall a. [a] -> [Int] -> [a]
shuffle xs swaps = runST $ do
    let n = length xs
    ar <- newListArray (1,n) xs :: ST s (STArray s Int a)
    for_ [1..n] $ \i ->
        for_ swaps $ \j -> do
            vi <- readArray ar i
            vj <- readArray ar j
            writeArray ar j vi
            writeArray ar i vj
    getElems ar
```

but I am not sure you can reasonably call it Fisher-Yates shuffle.

Comment: Note that, in the OP code, the shuffling was driven by the `swaps :: [Int]` argument rather than a randomness source, making the original function pure. It should be possible to achieve something similar in Haskell.

Comment: @chi Fair enough, added the code. Though I don't think this version can be called Fisher-Yates shuffle...

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I'm a bit of a Haskell noob so I'm trying to stay away from diving into the language extensions for now. Is there any way the implement that last implementation using swaps without `ScopedTypeVariables`?

Comment: never mind I was able to remove the ScopedTypeVariables without understanding what it was doing in the first place

Comment: @Julian The previous version (https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56662592/2) didn't have it, actually: `let newArray :: Int -> [a] -> ST s (STArray s Int a); newArray n xs = newListArray (1,n) xs` and then `ar <- newArray n xs`.